# GNU Parallel with processes that further fork

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

Consider the file `Processes.txt`

```
./MyProcess 1 -nbThreads 2
./MyProcess 2 -nbThreads 2
./MyProcess 3 -nbThreads 2
```

, where each `MyProcess` will attempt to use two cores. Now consider running

```
parallel -j 3 :::: Processes.txt
```

The call to `parallel` specifically indicate to use no more than 3 cores. Will `parallel` allow `MyProcess` to further fork and the whole thing will use 6 cores or will it somehow enforce the three processes `MyProcess` to using one core each only?

Comment: AFAIK it will run three processes at once and if they choose to create further processes it will neither know nor care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will run three processes at once and if they choose to create further processes it will neither know nor care.

(Hattip to: Mark Setchell)